# Prove that $ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r}\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda^{k+1}}d\lambda =\frac{t^k}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

Let $C_r$ be the circle centered on $0$ with radius $r$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$. How to show that $$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r}\frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda^{k+1}}d\lambda =\frac{t^k}{k!}$$

Comment: Does the integral somehow remind you of Cauchy?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I am stupid, Cauchy of derivatives didn't cross my mind :) thanks !

Answer (score 3):

A few possible methods:

1. Apply [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)
2. Put $\displaystyle e^{\lambda t} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \lambda^n$
   and integrate term-wise.
3. Integrate by parts. (Leads to induction on $k$)
4. Differentiate with respect to $t$.